# Validating a existence of a beta code before creating a User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, before-save

model: **User**

```
has_one :beta_invite

before_save :beta_code_must_exist

def beta_code_must_exist
    if beta_invite_id == beta_invite.find_by_name(beta_invite.id)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
end
```

model: **BetaInvite**

```
has_many :users
```

What I`m trying to do is check for the existence of a beta invite in DB, before allowing the user to be saved.

Since the User will be passing in the BetaInvite name into the field, I would like to check if it matches any existing Codes in the DB.

Hope I didn`t mix things up too much.

Would appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: Are you doing this check on user creation or at anytime the user record is saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a text field to the form for :beta_code
2. Add an attr_accessor for that field: attr_accessor :beta_code
3. Then add the following line to the model (Assumes you only want to do this check on user creation):

   `validate :beta_code_must_exist, :on => :create`
4. Change `beta_code_must_exist` to add an error to the form. Also be sure to properly cast :beta_code into the correct type.

   **Warning untested code below**

   ```
   def beta_code_must_exist
     @invite = BetaInvite.find_by_name(beta_code)
     if @invite.empty?
       errors.add(:beta_code, "is not a valid invite code")
     else
       beta_invite_id = @invite.id
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I don`t quite know how I`m suppose to check if the user.beta_invite_id (from the users form) matches the beta_invite.name (for the BetaInvite)

Comment: Does BetaInvite have both a name and an Id?

Comment: Wait does your user record exist at the time of doing this validation? My assumption in this answer is that this is a user signup page where a user record does not even exist yet therefore no prior beta_invite association.

Comment: To answer your first question, yes the BetaInvite does have a name & a  ID. The user friendly code name is defined as BetaInvite.name. The beta_invitation_id is (user model) is there so I can associate them properly. The user record doesn`t exist before entering the Beta Invite.

Comment: The line `if beta_invite_id == beta_invite.find_by_name(beta_invite.id)` has multiple problems I think. First if the user does not exist then it cannot 'has_one :beta_invite'. Second I think you have a typo `beta_invite.find_by_name` needs to be `BetaInvite.find_by_name`. Third that same line assumes both the id and the name are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:inclusion` with the `:in` option. You can supply `:in` with any enumerable:

```
validates :beta_invite, :inclusion => { :in => BetaInvite.all,
:message => "%{value} is not a valid beta invite code" }
```

Source: [Rails Active Record Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#inclusion)